# List and rename ADgroup in powershell

Tags: powershell, ps

am actually new on PS so I need to get some help running some commands.

Working on Active Directory, I need to get the name of a group and change its name, could be something like this.

`Get-ADGroup -Identity 'test' | set-adgroup -Identity 'test1'`

I already tried -SAMACCOUNTNAME as well.

Can I get some help please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity 'test' | Rename-ADObject -NewName 'test1'
```

have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/rename-adobject)

*"The Rename-ADObject cmdlet renames an Active Directory object. This cmdlet sets the Name property of an Active Directory object that has a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) display name (ldapDisplayName) of name. To modify the given name, surname, and other name of a user, use the Set-ADUser cmdlet. To modify the Security Account Manager (SAM) account name of a user, computer, or group, use the Set-ADUser, Set-ADComputer, or Set-ADGroup cmdlet."*

ps. for Get-ADGroup you need '-Identity' to be one of

- A distinguished name
- A GUID (objectGUID)
- A security identifier (objectSid)
- A security accounts manager account name (sAMAccountName)